# Captured groups variables not working in XRegexP javascript

Tags: regex, xregexp

```html
validLowToHigh = XRegExp('(?<kmHigh>[0-9]+) #capture \n\
                          (?:\\-|\\s) #dont capture\n\
                          (?<kmLow>[0-9]+) #capture','x')
```

If I remove the names like this it works

```html
validLowToHigh = XRegExp('([0-9]+) #capture \n\
                          (?:\\-|\\s) #dont capture\n\
                          ([0-9]+) #capture','x')
```

But I want to name the variables what I am I missing?

To text i'm matching is 1000-10000 which it does capture, how ever it not save the captures variables

Comment: Bueller? anyone

Answer (score 0):

I think it does save the captures. Looking at [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/), you could use named backreferences like:

```js
var validLowToHigh = XRegExp('(?<kmHigh>[0-9]+) #capture \n\
                            (?:\\-|\\s) #dont capture\n\
                            (?<kmLow>[0-9]+) #capture','x')

var result = XRegExp.exec('1000-10000', validLowToHigh);
console.log(result.kmHigh);
console.log(result.kmLow);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xregexp/xregexp-all.js"></script>
```